# Netcode NetworkVariables not synced across clients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on my first online card game.
As part of the initial stage of the game, each players needs to sort his cards, and only after the two players finished sorting their cards, the game can begin.

I added a `NetworkVariable<int>` to the player's `NetworkBehvior` with the initial value of 0, and i'm trying to raise it by 1 whenever a player is ready, so when the value is 2, i can move on to the next stage of the game.
I followed the docs and a few tutorials, but nothing seems to work correctly.
Whatever i do, its looks like the clients only updates their own instance of the value and that its not synced between them.

My `PlayerController` `NetworkBehvior` looks like this:

```
private GameMaster gameMaster;
private NetworkVariable<int> playersReady = new NetworkVariable<int>();

public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
{
    base.OnNetworkSpawn();
    playersReady.OnValueChanged += (previousValue, newValue) =>
    {
        if (IsHost && playersReady.Value == 2)
        {
            // move to start phase of the game
        }
    };

}

private void Update()
{
    if (!IsOwner) return;

    if (GameMaster.Singleton.playerSelectedTableCards)
    {
        GameMaster.Singleton.playerSelectedTableCards = false;
        // do some work

        playersReady.Value++;

    }
}
```

I also tried updated the value via ServerRpc method

```
[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
void AddPlayerReady1_ServerRpc()
{
    playersReady.Value++;
}
```

That gave me even weirder results. both clients (a host and a client) called this ServerRpc, both got to the host instance of the script, but in both times previous value of 0 and current value of 1, which leads me to think they are still different NetworkValue instances somehow.

Would love to have some insights.

Comment: afaik you have to do his on the server -> syncs down to clients not the other way round => instead send an Rpc to the server and only modify the variable on the server -> then it will be synced down to all clients

Comment: That gave me even weirder results. both clients (a host and a client) called this ServerRpc, both got to the host instance of the script, but both were previous value of 0 and current value of 1. which leads me to think they are still different NetworkValue instances.

Comment: well yes, thinking about it, they indeed are ^^ You have different instances of your player .. one for each player individually. They are both synced correctly but are not connected in any way

Comment: according to unity's docs "At a high level, a NetworkVariable is a way to synchronize a property ("variable") between a server and client(s) without having to use custom messages or RPCs."
I believe the whole point of NetworkVariables is to be shared on the network between clients. (i also saw a tutorial or two who shows how to use it for this purpose, but i wasn't able to make work while doing the same thing).
Am i missing something?

Comment: I think in your case you will want to go with a central scene object that is owned and controlled only by the server - see https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/networkvariable/#onvaluechanged-example every local client would go through that central controller calls an RPC, that RPC increases the value on the server and it gets synced down to everyone / the server starts the game when enough clients are there etc